# Add a bookmarklet in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am currently running Chrome 11.  I have been trying to figure out how to add a bookmarklet (which should be dead simple) and it's driving me crazy.  This is the site I'm trying to drag the bookmarklet from http://gridder.andreehansson.se/

First off it seems there is no such thing as the bookmark bar anymore (or I just can't find it for some odd reason) so there is no where to really drag a bookmarklet.  The bookmarks page opens as a new tab, so there isn't really any dragging option there.

Then even if I wanted to use the bookmarklet, there is no bookmarks drop down from a page tab, I always have to open a new page so there is no context to run the bookmarklet in.

I'm not a big fan of how Chrome is doing bookmarks now as it really puts them out of the way and requires more clicks than before.  Does anyone have the flow that works for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a bookmark bar, you just have to go to "View" and then click "Always Show Bookmarks Bar". You can also use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: There is no 'View' in Chrome 11

Comment: @Scott: Try Control+Shift+B

Comment: that worked.  I wish the Chrome team wouldn't hide more features behind commands.  I really hate that the bookmarks are now on a bookmark page too.

Comment: @Scott: I'm glad it worked, I added it to my answer. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 22):

1. (If you don't see the bookmark bar) CTRL-SHIFT-B
2. Right-click on the bookmark bar to get the dropdown menu
3. Choose Bookmark Manager
4. Right-click again (anywhere) and choose 'Add new bookmark'
5. Type in a name for it.
6. In the URL part, if you are adding a javascript bookmarklet, paste the javscript code in.  You have to prefex it with `javascript:`
   and it should minified and free of comments.

You can also use a service like: [bookmarkleter](http://chriszarate.github.io/bookmarkleter/)

Answer (score 1):

On the bookmark bar far left you will see the small globe next to the new tab. Right click it. the drop down will then have the option to add a page.